# return json from php and handle

Tags: php, jquery, json

I get this from ajax call

```
{"id":"381120774951940096","time":"Posted 0 minutes and 51 seconds ago.",....
```

How can I add each of these into variable, id, time etc? data.id won't work, it says undef.

```
<script>
$(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "start.php",
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data.name);
                console.log(data);
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

This is what I return from start.php

```
$return = array('id' => $info['id_str'] ,'time' => timeDiff(new DateTime($info['created_at'])), 'name' => $info['user']['name'], 'text' => $info['text'], 'image' => $picture, 'url' => "http://twitter.com/{$info['user']['screen_name']}");

print_r(json_encode($return));
```

**EDIT**
I had that print_r inside foreach loop and that was the issue. So I added another array and used echo json_decode($array,true) at the end of file.Writing this just in case, might help someone.

Cheers

Comment: why print_r? echo is perfectly fine!

Comment: I'm just used to print_r.

Answer (score 0):

First, in your PHP, change your line to:

```
echo json_encode($return, true);
```

That second parameter ensures that the JSON is interpretable as an associative array. Also, you should use **`echo`** instead of `print_r` when returning JSON; `print_r` can alter the formatting.

Next, use the following AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "start.php",
    dataType: "json", // Add this option.
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data.name);
        console.log(data);
    }
})
```

The `dataType: "json"` option ensures that `data` will be parsed as a JSON object as soon as it's retrieved. So, `data.id` should be immediately available in your `success` callback function.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm not getting anything in console log when I add  dataType: "json" in ajax call. I tried to set headers to json in php file and same result.

Comment: Did you make sure to switch to `echo` instead of `print_r`?

Comment: also, it helps to put `ob_end_clean();` before the echo, and `exit;` after it.

Comment: @MightyPork That helped a lot! I had echo in foreach loop and thats the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should use `echo` in the server script. `print_r` is mainly for debugging arrays.

Secondly, you should declare a `dataType` option for the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json", // <-- here
    type: "POST",
    url: "start.php",
    cache: false,

    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data.name);
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

The way you have it now, I think you are getting a string response as data.

You can verify that with `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));`

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `dataType: 'json'` in your ajax. This means that jQuery will parse the result as JSON for you.

Then parse the data,

```
 data = $.parseJSON(data);
```

Then read `var id = data.id;`

Also,  in your PHP, No need to use print_r(). Just use echo instead print_r().like:

```
echo json_encode($return);
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to parse the JSON string into an object. You can use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to do this.

```
// Your JSON string
var json_str = "{'id': 'foo', 'time': 'bar'}";

// We need to parse it, converting it into a JS object
var json_obj = JSON.parse(json_str);

// We can now interact with it
console.log(json_obj.id);
console.log(json_obj.time);
```

Alternatively, you can parse JSON using a built in jQuery function [parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/).

jQuery also has a built in function for fetching JSON called [getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/). If memory serves, this is just a shorthand for doing an `.ajax()` call and specifying a datatype of `json`. This will handle the above (parsing JSON) for you, and is the recommended solution.

Comment: jQuery does this for you, just define a `dataType` parameter. You are solving a situation that shouldn't have happened in the first place - such an approach is wrong.

Comment: Also, `var json_str = {"...` is **NOT** a string.

Comment: I very obviously indicated that dataType should be set in the bottom portion of my post. The root cause is indicated, and addressed at the top as a matter of completeness (i.e. This is WHY it broke). I'll grant you the last point and have updated accordingly.